# How to put variable in validation custom error message in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to put an object attribute inside custom error message, like that:

```
validates_attachment :picture, 
:content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpeg"], message: "File type is invalid: #{object.file_name}" }
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can only access the `attribute`(being validated) and its value in the `message` option of `validates` method in a given model.

Here's a work-around:

```
validates_attachment :picture, 
:content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpeg"], message: "File type is invalid:" } ## Remove #{object.file_name}
```

In the view, where you are displaying the validation error messages:

```
  <% model_instance.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <% if msg == "Picture File type is invalid:" %>  ## full_messages prepends attribute name to message
      <p><%= msg + "#{model_instance.picture_file_name}" %></p>
    <% else %>
      <p><%= msg %></p>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**NOTE:** Replace `model_instance` with your instance of model passed in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%{value}` instead of  `#{object.file_name}`

```
validates_attachment :picture, 
:content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpeg"], message: "File type is invalid: %{value}" }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to put there an attribute of created object. Is it possible?

Comment: %{value} returns the value that is being validated. If file name is being validated in `validates_attachment`, you will get that as output.

Comment: Yes, but I don't need to validate the file name. I just wanted to put some info (file name) to the message of file which validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 days on this but managed to find a really clean work around that keeps all the code in a simple method in the model itself - which is where we want to handle validations without having to worry about the view.

1. Allow the validation message to be created as normal, you don't need to try and change it in the validation helper.
2. create an `after_validation` callback that will replace that validation message in the back-end before it gets to the view.
3. In the `after_validation` method you can use dynamic values and insert them into the validation message.

---

```
#this could be any validation
validates_attachment :picture, :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpeg"], message: "Add anything you want here we will replace it anyway" }

after_validation :replace_validation_message

def replace_validation_message
    custom_value = #any value you would like
    errors.messages[:name_of_the_attribute] = ["This is the replacement message where 
    you can now add your own dynamic values!!! #{custom_value}"]
end
```

The `after_validation` method will have far greater scope than the built in rails validation helper, so you will be able to access the object you are validating like you are trying to do with `object.file_name`. Which does not work in the validation helper where you are trying to call it.